# Print Highest Pythagorean Triple - C

Tags: c, pythagorean

so far this program prints all the triples and tells you if a number entered has no triples. I need it to print the triple with highest value of C again after it lists all the triples.
[Example I/O for this project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2pgVR.png)

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{

    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, n;
    int counter = 0;    // counter for # of triples

    printf("Please Enter a Positive Integer: \n"); //asks for number
    scanf_s("%d", &n); //gets number

    for (c = 0; c < n; c++)  //for loops counting up to the number
    {
        for (b = 0; b < c; b++)
        {
            for (a = 0; a < b; a++)
            {
                if (a * a + b * b == c * c) //pythag to check if correct
                {
                    printf("%d: \t%d %d %d\n", ++counter, a, b, c); //prints triples in an orderd list

                }
                else if (n < 6) // if less than 6 - no triples
                {
                    printf("There is no pythagorean triple in this range");
                }
            }
        }
    }
    getch(); //stops program from closing until you press a keys
}
```

If I type 15 into N it will print:

```
3 4 5
6 8 10
5 12 13
```

So the last triple it prints always has the highest value of C (5 12 13) but I need to print a statement saying that specific triple has the highest.

Comment: Do not post external links or images unless absolutely necessary!

Comment: You could simply use 3 additional variables to track the triple with the largest value of C. Whether you count up or count down, you'll still need those 3 variables.

Comment: @ChronoKitsune Could you explain how I could implement them to keep track of the value? I'm very much a novice, thanks!

Comment: @Miragee13 You'd start with `int max_A, max_B, max_C = 0;` (note: only max_C is 0 here; the other values are unknown). When you find a triple, check if `c > max_C`. If that is true, then you'd replace the maximum value of A, B, C with the current value of a, b, c.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this, I am sure you can improve on that, it works but I am running out of time to clean it, so have fun !

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main(  )
{

  int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0, n;
  int counter = 0;      // counter for # of triples
  int triple_sum[6];
  int sums = 0;
  int triple_high_sum = 0;
  int triple_high_index = 0;

  printf( "Please Enter a Positive Integer: \n" );  //asks for number
  scanf( "%d", &n );        //gets number

  for ( c = 0; c < n; c++ ) //for loops counting up to the number
  {
    for ( b = 0; b < c; b++ )
    {
      for ( a = 0; a < b; a++ )
      {
    if ( a * a + b * b == c * c )   //pythag to check if correct
    {
      printf( "%d: \t%d %d %d\n", counter, a, b, c );   
     //prints triples in an orderd list
      triple_sum[counter++] = a + b + c;

    }
    else if ( n < 6 )   // if less than 6 - no triples
    {
      printf( "There is no pythagorean triple in this range" );
      break;
    }
      }             // endfor

    }               // endfor
  }

  sums = --counter;
  triple_high_sum = -1;
  if ( sums )
    while ( sums > -1 )
    {
      printf( "\ntriple_sum %d == %d", sums, triple_sum[sums] );
      if ( triple_sum[sums] > triple_high_sum )
      {
    triple_high_sum = triple_sum[sums];
    triple_high_index = sums;
      }
      sums--;
    }               // endwhile

  if ( triple_high_sum > -1 )
    printf( "\nThe triple index with the largest value is %d",
        triple_high_index );

  getchar(  );          //stops program from closing until you press a keys
}
        //stop
```